# WordPress : Set post author with text input

Tags: php, wordpress, author

In WordPress administration I have 1800 users. When I want to publish a post, I have to choose the author out of the drop down menu (metaboxes author). This is very annoying.

I would like to be able to choose the author by typing her ID or username in a text input field.

Core's WordPress only has `wp_dropdown_users()` to set the author.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Write new plugin, where you can modify author metabox. Create textbox instead of dropdown, with search function using ajax, so you can search and select author.

Comment: it's not so easy! ;(

Comment: I know its not easy, i just gave you an idea to make it. Code it, and then ask your queries here, i am sure you will get better help. :)

Comment: i don't how to start now...

Comment: Then i am afraid, this question will going to close soon, as it is off topic.

Comment: It can be a good solution for post administration?
https://webdevstudios.com/2015/08/11/replacing-default-wordpress-user-dropdowns-ajax-solution/

Comment: You can't decide without trying it, just try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WebDevStudios Dynamic Dropdowns plugin, which does exactly what you asked for.

Currently you can download it only from GitHub: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS-Dynamic-Dropdowns

Comment: Et voilà. Thank You Chris. :) I just installed now, and ur plgn works fine.